# Compile Error: “Not a statement”

Tags: java

```
public class Hello
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     int i = 1;
     for(i; ;i++ )
     {
        System.out.println(i);
     }      
}
```

}

I would like to understand why above code is giving error as:

> not a statement for(i ; ; i++)

Comment: Probably because that is not valid Java. Look at the  [for Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: first part of `for` must be a statement. i is not a statement, write i=1 or nothing there
`for(i=1;;i++)` or `for(;;i++)`

Comment: `i` is an *expression*, `i=...` is a statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the raw `i` in the first position of your `for` is *not a statement*. You can declare and initialize variables in a `for` loop in Java. So, I think you wanted something like

```
// int i = 1;
for(int i = 1; ;i++ )
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

If you need to access `i` after your loop you could also use

```
int i;
for(i = 1; ; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Or even

```
int i = 1;
for(; ; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

This is covered by [JLS-14.4. The `for` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14) which says (in part)

> A for statement is executed by first executing the ForInit code:
>
> If the ForInit code is a list of statement expressions ([§14.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)), the expressions are evaluated in sequence from left to right; their values, if any, are discarded.

Answer (score 3):

The lone i at the start of the for statement doesn't make any sense - it's not a statement. Typically the variable of the for loop is initialized in the for statement as such:

```
for(int i = 1;; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

This will loop forever though, as there is no test to break out of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop to:

```
 for(; ;i++ )
```

It will loop infinitely printing i. Your i is not of boolean type which you could have place in condition of for loop and for loop has format like:

```
for (init statement; condition; post looping)
```

So in your init statement you just had i which is not a valid statement and hence you get error from compiler.